# How to get ALL DataGrid's selected Item. (MOST up to date)

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, selecteditemchanged

I am currently trying to get a collection of selected datagrid rows selected by the user (multi row selection on).

Each row is binded to a visual object which i want to show as selected"

So for the data grid I added this style:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="DataGrid_RowSelectionChanged" />
</Style>
```

So when the user selects a row I get an event fired.

However, when select a row and into the event. Selected item has not been updated yet and it still shows what I PREVIOUSLY selected. DataGrid.CurrentItem shows the row I just clicked and about to be selected, but since its multi select, I want to be able to get ALL the rows CURRENTLY selected and have my visual object "Highlighted"

Is there a way where I can get a MOST updated list of selected item from datagrid? Is there an event I can use that fires AFTER i selected my new row?

Thanks and Regards,
Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [DataGrid.SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) event. The `SelectionChangedEventArgs` will contain the items which were added or removed at the time of selection changing.

```
        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
        dg.SelectionChanged += new System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler(OnSelectionChanged);

        void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var addedItem in e.AddedItems)
            {
                //do stuff
            }

            foreach (var removedItem in e.RemovedItems)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
```